# Objective-c FMDB SQLite insert withParameterDictionary and auto-increment key

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

I have an iOS app using FMDB library.

There is a 7 field SQLite DB (1 autoincrement, 6 regular text fields).

I am trying to execute

```
 [db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO messages  VALUES (:field1,:field2,:field3,:field4,:field5,:field6)" withParameterDictionary:message];
```

However because there are only 6 fields I get an error. I cannot insert the autoincrement value, since I do not know what it is (I guess I could put a separate query for that...). And I am trying to avoid injection-susceptible syntax

```
NSString* sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into messages (%@) values (%@)", [newCols componentsJoinedByString:@", "], [newVals componentsJoinedByString:@", "]];
```

Thank you for advice!

Comment: I suppose you have an ID column that is auto incremented. You don't have to provide anything for this column as it is automatically inserted by the DB.

Comment: If I omit :primarykey  in the values part, I get error:
    table messages has 7 columns but 6 values were supplied; 

If I send a nil object for pk I get error
    Error: the bind count (6) is not correct for the # of variables in the query (7); 

If I use @"" for primary key I get "datatype mismatch" since primary key in integer.

Comment: Did you see my answer and does it help you?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify which column was the autoincrement column so I'll assume it's simply "field1".  When you build your dictionary, add this:

```
[message setObject:[NSNull null] forKey:@"field1"];
```

then

```
[db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO messages  VALUES (:field1,:field2,:field3,:field4,:field5,:field6)" withParameterDictionary:message];
```

Be sure to change "field1" to whatever field you are using for autoincrement.

Comment: Nope. You do not need/must not specify the auto increment field.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a look in my code where I also used FMDB. First of all you also have to provide the columns your insert statement. This is what I do:

```
NSString *sqlSL = @"INSERT INTO SmartLibrary (TITEL, SUBTITEL, PICTURE, BLURB, MARK) VALUES (?, ? ,? ,? ,?)";
[db beginTransaction];
[db executeUpdate:sqlSL, book.title, book.subtitle, book.picture, book.summary, [NSNumber numberWithInteger:book.mark]];
[db commit];
```

I have a structure Book in this case. So what you need to do is provide the columns affected by this insert in parentheses. Also you can see how to make a prepared statement and you should use transactions. Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because of a typo I oversaw looking at the code a hundred times: one of the dictionary keys was wrong. In this case, FMDB prints the following error to the debug console:

```
Could not find index for <wrong_dict_key_name>
```

The next error FMDB prints to the console is a little misleading:

```
Error: the bind count (6) is not correct for the # of variables in the query (7) (INSERT INTO ...
```

The root cause is of course the wrong dictionary key.